# Sqlite database operation shows "table name = null" in stacktrace

Tags: android, sqlite

I m new to android operating system. I have developed one application which is running fine. But in logcat I always get following lines.

```
04-29 10:21:44.263: D/Cursor(2101): Database path: mydb
04-29 10:21:44.263: D/Cursor(2101): Table name   : null
```

I want to know why these lines come in logcat. Am I doing something wrong? Following is the code I m using for my application.

```
 public ArrayList<LD> fetchData() {
    String C="c",query;
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    LD lData = null;
    ArrayList<LD> myData = new ArrayList<LD>();
    try{ 
        openDBConnection(); //open database

        query = "SELECT * FROM ANDROID_DATA WHERE STATUS = '" + C +"';";
        mCursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                lData = new LD();
                String id = mCursor.getString(0);
                lData.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                lData.setFName(mCursor.getString(1));
                lData.setLName(mCursor.getString(2));

                java.util.Date ct = new java.util.Date(mCursor.getLong(3));                 
                lData.setCreatedTime(ct);

                myData.add(lData);                      
            } while(mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //TODO: Handle Excaption
    } finally {
        closeDBConnection(); //close database
    }
    return myData;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing to close cursor.. Add following lines in your code..
Just close your cursor in finally block..

```
public ArrayList<LD> fetchData() {
    String C="c",query;
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    LD lData = null;
    ArrayList<LD> myData = new ArrayList<LD>();
    try{ 
        openDBConnection(); //open database

        query = "SELECT * FROM ANDROID_DATA WHERE STATUS = '" + C +"';";
        mCursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                lData = new LD();
                String id = mCursor.getString(0);
                lData.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                lData.setFName(mCursor.getDouble(1));
                lData.setLName(mCursor.getDouble(2));

                java.util.Date ct = new java.util.Date(mCursor.getLong(4));                 
                lData.setCreatedTime(ct);

                myData.add(locData);                        
            } while(mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //TODO: Handle Excaption
    } finally {
        try{
            if (mCursor != null ) {
                mCursor.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
        closeDBConnection(); //close database
    }
    return myData;  
}
```

Hope this will work for you..